# rails call action in controller and get data with click and pop up modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

I want to call action in controller and get data on link click and pop up modal based on data. So far I have tried out below code and it is not loading data.

```
<%= link_to  image_tag("notif.png", :title=>"Notifications"), notificationsget_path,  :remote => true,                               
                                :data => {:toggle=>"modal", :target=>"#notifmodal"}%>
```

Please advice me as I am new to Rails.

Comment: your looking for a pop up modal on click right?

Answer (score -1):

Can you try this as a test

```
   <%= link_to "Show", avail_index_path, "data-toggle" => "modal", "data-target" => "#dialogAvail", class: "showClass" %>
```

Comment: now the modal is showing but the data is not loaded as expected. Is there a way to wait till getting data and load the modal